# how to make doxygen to document only exportted tcl functions from a package

Tags: tcl, doxygen

Is there an easy way to make doxygen to document only exportted tcl functions from a package. A command in config file maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I previously used doxygen for Tcl doc generation before tcl was a supported language.  There is a config option for processing the input files.

```
FILTER_PATTERNS = *.tcl=bin\tcl_converter.bat
```

where bin\tcl_converter.bat would just be a batch script that launches a custom processor.  We used it to minimally change the tcl syntax into something that doxygen would understand before the tcl support was added.  But, you could use it here to just remove all of the non-exported methods.  It would be pretty simple to write a processor to just drop all non-exported procs.  Something like:

1. Read input file (it will be passed as [lindex $argv 0]) into an
   array of lines
2. Loop through all of the lines looking for export commands
3. Loop through all of the lines looking for procs and match against the exported commands listed above
4. Save up all of the current procedure and its preamble in a string - write to the output
   file at the end if it matches an exported command

A proper parser would make this foolproof, but is probably overkill.  You can just look for the beginning of a namespace and the beginning of a proc and set up a state machine.  Once you start a namespace, just keep appending every line to a string and test with **info complete $accumulated_ns_string** .  Similarly once you see a **proc** command, start accumlating the lines into a different string and keep checking after each line with **info complete $accumulated_proc_string**.  Once that evals to true, you can print or not print and reset the strings.

Using the **info complete** will simplify life a lot - all of the trickery will be in keeping track of the namespaces and evaluating the fully qualified proc name against fully qualified exported names to determine whether or not to print it to the output file.  There are some pathological cases of code occurring outside of a namespace or dynamically generated exports, but this approached worked well enough in my previous job against everything we threw at it.